# How do I upscale the size of everything?

Tags: display, screen, hdpi

I am using Ubuntu in VB so I can get the hang of it and eventually switch to Linux. However, I have a 4k screen (I forget the exact pixel by pixel but I can find out if I must) and everything is downscaled way too small to the point I have to put my face right in front of the screen to see what i'm doing. Things like apps and the time. How do I upscale everything so I can actually see what I'm doing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: System Settings/Display/Resolution.

Comment: What @EODCraftStaff tried to say is: lower the Screen Resolution within VB and you might have to deactivate the automatic Screen Resize

Comment: Another way which I would prefer in your case would be changing the Screen Textsize and Icon Size also in the System settings. On this way you would still be able to keep all benefits of being able to automatically resize the VMs Screen